# Mongoengine Document.update() example

Tags: mongoengine

Assuming that Venue is:

```py
from mongoengine import *
from mongoengine_extras.fields import  AutoSlugField
class Venue(Document):
    name = StringField(required=True)
    venue_slug = AutoSlugField()
```

I want to update all my venue_slug fields based on the name. I try:

```py
for v in Venue.objects():
    v(venue_slug = str(v.name)).update()
```

But I get:

```py
v(venue_slug = str(v.name)).update()
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
'Venue' object is not callable
```

Is my update function correct? If you are not familiar with `AutoSlugField()` could you write an example for a `StringField()` update?

Answer (score 12):

Your code incorrect. Try:

```
for v in Venue.objects():
    v.update(set__venue_slug=str(v.name))
```

See documentation: http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html#atomic-updates.

Comment: `set__` can be omitted here as well since the default operation is set.

Comment: @NicholasRempel that is no longer the case.  I just received an error stating that I have to provide an operation